# Running daemonized Bottle app with ability to change server

Tags: python, daemon, bottle

**What problem I have:**

I need to **properly** launch my Bottle application in daemon mode, while keeping **all** features of `bottle.run()` command.

**What did I tried:**

1. Using `BottleDaemon`. It doesn't suit me, because I need to change server variable (and perharps more actions with `bottle.run()` in future), but `bottledaemon.daemon_run()` doesn't support it.
2. `daemonize.py`. Process exits without any logs and stdout/stderr.
3. Putting my Bottle app into `supervisor`. My shell account doesn't have access to root or sudo, and I think that's why it drops me a `Permission denied` error on `subprocess.Popen`.

upd. Here's traceback when I try to launch bottle app via `supervisor`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maxlunar/bottle/app.py", line 20, in <module>
    run(server='tornado', host='xxxx', port=xxxxx, reloader=True)
  File "/home/maxlunar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bottle.py", line 3079, in run
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, env=environ)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1282, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

It still runs perfectly without `supervisor`:

```
(bottle) maxlunar@Lydia:bottle$ python app.py
Bottle v0.12.13 server starting up (using TornadoServer())...
Listening on http://xxxxx:xxxxx/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

Is theres another way to fix my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: “Process exits without any logs and stdout/stderr” — I assume you mean the daemon process? the one whose PID is written to the pidfile? (because the parent process is supposed to exit silently)

Comment: [`daemonize.py`](https://github.com/thesharp/daemonize/blob/master/daemonize.py) is not a big program. You might be able to debug it by inserting debug writes in a few places, or perhaps removing the `os.dup2` calls whereby it redirects stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`.

Comment: In general, there are many tools to daemonize a process under Unix — such as [`daemon`](http://libslack.org/daemon/), or even something as simple as `nohup python yourscript.py &` — but given that already two of such solutions are not working for you, it might be a good idea to understand why.

Comment: `Process exits without any logs and stdout/stderr` I'm not sure `daemonize` means what you think it means. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ron.rothman I have access to shell in a linux server, but not root or sudo. I want my bottle app running even if I close shell session.

Comment: Have you tried `nohup python myscript.py &`?

Comment: @ron.rothman Yes, it works. Thank you.

Comment: Great! This was a classic XY Problem. I'll convert my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer is based on additional info from OP in comments.)

To run your server in the background and have it *not* exit when you log out, you can use `nohup`:

```
nohup python myscript.py &
```

Comment: What about automatically reloading it, if server restarts for some reason, without root?